# Diodes in AC current

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

If in AC current, the direction of the current is always changing, then if one was to place a diode (for simplicities sake lets say an LED) in an AC current, would it flash to the frequency of the alternations? (assuming that the LED can withstand the current in both directions without being damaged)

i would have thought that because the potential difference can only produce a current in the correct polarity for half the time, the current could only flow in the right direction half the time and hence the LED would flash.

Comment: try it and find out

Comment: You might be interested in this Wikipedia article: [Rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN ac frequency,the range of 50 to 60hz even though the connected led blinks it cannot be visible to human eye.
      in above mention that led can with stand in dual polarity but inrush current in ac will affect it.
      If you slow down the freq then blinking will visible

Comment: If you move it very quickly you will still be able to see the on-off cycle at 60Hz as streaks.